# How to Insert For In Loop Variable into Variable Call

Tags: java, flutter, variables, naming

```
    class GraphData {
    List <double> closingPricesBTC = [];
    List <double> closingPricesETH = [];
    List <double> closingPricesLTC = [];

        for (String cryptoCurrency in cryptoAbbreviation){
        .
        . (some code)
        .
        double closePrice = ....

        closingPrices.add(closePrice);
        }
```

}

where cryptoAbbreviation is

```
const List<String> cryptoAbbreviation = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC'];
```

How can I append the current "cryptocurrency" String into the name of the variable for `closingPrices.add(closePrice)` so that I can end up with `closingPricesBTC.add(closePrice)`, `closingPricesETH.add(closePrice)`, and `closingPricesLTC.add(closePrice)`

I've tried `closingPrices$cryptoCurrency.add(closePrice);` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can't "make up" variable names on-the-fly at runtime in Java.

Comment: it doesn't work in flutter also

Comment: The thing to do here would be to put your `List<Double>`s (**not** `List<double>`) in a `Map<String, List<Double>>` with the abbreviations as the keys.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, yeah, I was writing the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate variable names but you can try HashMap(Java)/Map(Dart).  This should fulfill your requirement.

```
Map<String, List<double>> closingPrices = {'BTC':[], 'ETH':[], 'LTC':[]};


        for (String cryptoCurrency in cryptoAbbreviation){
        .
        . (some code)
        .
        double closePrice = ....

        closingPrices[cryptoCurrency].add(closePrice);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this and report back to let you know if this works for me.